# How to add an image file as a header to every print job programmatically in C/C++/C#?

Tags: c++, windows, printing, header, desktop

So basically, I have no idea where to start since I'm not actually a desktop developer.

I'm a web dev but we need this functionality in our current project with a client but sadly we don't have background knowledge for this and we have been searching for ways how to do it and so far we are convinced that we need C/C++/C# for this.

But the problem is how or in where do we start? The use case for this is very few and thus too little Documentation is available especially in forums.

We would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would constitute a "print job"?

Comment: When a user wants to print a document from their machine either from apps like word or acrobat.

Comment: C and C++ don't know what an image is, let alone what a printer is, without a lot of help.

Comment: What help do we need in this case?

Comment: Adobe has a c++ [open source library](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/apireference/index.html) see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, any info related to this is highly appreciated.

Comment: @doug I think the OP is talking about creating a custom [separator page](https://superuser.com/a/976573) that Windows printer driver allows, but somewhat more advanced one, with an image instead of just text. I'm afraid this requires creating and installing a custom printer driver.

Comment: Could we create the printer driver instead?